# Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.TypeException: does not have a no-arg constructor

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

I tried make an apex class with invocable Param, but i got **Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.TypeException: UT_Recalcuate_CallAction.recordInfo does not have a no-arg constructor** when i tried add @TestVisible.

if i dont add the @TestVisible my test class get error **Constructor not defined: [UT_Recalcuate_CallAction.recordInfo].(Id)**

Do you guys have any idea what should i do? Thank you.

This is my apex class

```
public class UT_Recalcuate_CallAction {

    public String valQli;

    public class recordInfo {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String recordId;
        
        @TestVisible
        recordInfo( String recordId) {
            this.recordId = recordId;
        }
    }

    public UT_Recalcuate_CallAction(String quoVal){
    this.valQli= quoVal;
    }
    
    public class Results {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Output' description='description' required=true)
        public String outputMember;
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'UT_Recalcuate_CallAction')
    public static List<Results> execute(recordInfo[] lstRecordInfo) {
        //mylogic
    }
}
```

This is my test class

```
@IsTest(seeAllData=TRUE)
public class UT_FSL_Recalculate_Total_Test {
    static testMethod void recalculateMethod(){
        Test.startTest();

        Quote_Product_Item__c qpiList = [SELECT Quote__c,id, Quote_Line_Item__c FROM Quote_Product_Item__c Order by Quote__c LIMIT 1];
        UT_Recalcuate_CallAction.execute(new UT_Recalcuate_CallAction.recordInfo[] {
            new UT_Recalcuate_CallAction.recordInfo(id.valueof(qpiList.Quote__c))
        });
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why does your `UT_Recalcuate_CallAction` [sic] class have a parameterized constructor and can't you make your `recordInfo` constructor `public`? BTW, it's bad practice to have `SeeAllData` set `true`...

Comment: I tried same code in questions, and it's working fine for me. Seems like issue is in logic or something else. Try commenting you logic and just execute skeleton to narrow down the root cause.